# Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID '2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52'. Try pre-importing one of these assemblies

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a project that I have converted from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. 
In Visual Studio 2010 when building the project I get the following error:

> Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID
>   '2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52'.  Try pre-importing one of
>   these assemblies.

This did not happen in VS2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly error building app - Encountered multiple versions of assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901052/assembly-error-building-app-encountered-multiple-versions-of-assembly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more than 1 version of MS Office installed?
The GUID '2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52' refers to Office